# Erase repeated rows from a cell array

Tags: string, matlab, cell, repeat

I have a cell array with a lot of rows and sometimes it happens that the rows repeat. In that sense I would like to erase the rows that are repeated, only keeping the first one. It is important to know that I am dealing mostly with string values, meaning regular and useful functions do not work. Could someone help me please? Here is an example:

```
19970101 18659 183 '19980820' '00018659' 'RUNYON L' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
19970101 18290 183 '19981221' '00018290' 'MANTON S' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
19970101 10280 183 '19980819' '00010280' 'BRENNAN S' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
19970101 18659 183 '19980820' '00018659' 'RUNYON L' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
19970101 10280 183 '19980819' '00010280' 'BRENNAN S' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
```

What I would like to get:

```
19970101 18659 183 '19980820' '00018659' 'RUNYON L' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
19970101 18290 183 '19981221' '00018290' 'MANTON S' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
19970101 10280 183 '19980819' '00010280' 'BRENNAN S' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
```

Comment: You could use the third output of `unique`, and attack the cell column by column.


`[~,~,a] = unique([cell_array{:,1}])`

Answer (score 3):

You can first sort the rows of your cell array (`sortrows`), and then you can identify duplicate rows with linear complexity (`isequal` applied to consecutive rows).

Let `cellArray` denote your input cell array:

```
cellArray = {19970101 18659 183 '19980820' '00018659' 'RUNYON L' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
             19970101 18290 183 '19981221' '00018290' 'MANTON S' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
             19970101 10280 183 '19980819' '00010280' 'BRENNAN S' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
             19970101 18659 183 '19980820' '00018659' 'RUNYON L' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
             19970101 10280 183 '19980819' '00010280' 'BRENNAN S' '00001534' 'MERRILL'}
```

Code:

```
[sorted, jj] = sortrows(cellArray);
ind = arrayfun(@(n) isequal(sorted(n,:),sorted(n+1,:)), 1:size(cellArray,1)-1);
result = cellArray(sort(jj([true ~ind])),:);
```

Result:

```
result = 
    [19970101]    [18659]    [183]    '19980820'    '00018659'    'RUNYON L'     '00001534'    'MERRILL'
    [19970101]    [18290]    [183]    '19981221'    '00018290'    'MANTON S'     '00001534'    'MERRILL'
    [19970101]    [10280]    [183]    '19980819'    '00010280'    'BRENNAN S'    '00001534'    'MERRILL'
```

Comment: I was under the impression cell arrays can't be sorted by rows. Looking into it, but wow awesome! One more +1!!

Comment: It's been a surprise also for me. I began by converting to strings as you do, but then I decided to try with the original array

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks for your code. I have been off for too long and only now was I able to try it! But starting with the first line it is already giving error! `>> [sorted, Jj] = sortrows(FINALJOIN2);
Error using char
Cell elements must be character arrays.

Error in sortrows>sort_cell_back_to_front (line 136)
            tmp = char(x(ndx,k));

Error in sortrows (line 88)
        ndx = sort_cell_back_to_front(x_sub, col);`

Comment: I believe the problem is most likely with the type of my data. I will check it. Thanks.

Comment: @LuisMendo I managed to solve my problem, and I believe your code will be very useful to me. Thank you. I am learning a lot of new things I never imagined I would.

Comment: @user3557054 Glad about that :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
%// Input cell array
input_cell_array ={
    19970101 18659 183 '19980820' '00018659' 'RUNYON L' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
    19970101 18290 183 '19981221' '00018290' 'MANTON S' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
    19970101 10280 183 '19980819' '00010280' 'BRENNAN S' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
    19970101 18659 183 '19980820' '00018659' 'RUNYON L' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
    19970101 10280 183 '19980819' '00010280' 'BRENNAN S' '00001534' 'MERRILL'}

%// "Standardize" the cells by converting all into strings
allstrc = cellfun(@num2str,input_cell_array,'uni',0)

%// Group each column as one cell for labelling them
allstrcg = mat2cell(allstrc,size(allstrc,1),ones(1,size(allstrc,2)))

%// Label them with unique command
[~,~,row_ind] = cellfun(@(x) unique(x,'stable'),allstrcg,'uni',0)

%// Sometimes the row_ind obtained from the earlier code are obtained in cells
%// as row or column vectors, so we need to normalize them -
row_ind = cellfun(@(x) reshape(x,[],1),row_ind,'uni',0) 

%// Get a double array of the labels 
mat1 = horzcat(row_ind{:})

%// Get unique rows of the labels
[~,ind] = unique(mat1,'rows','stable')

%// Finally get the desired output by selecting the unique rows from the labels
out = input_cell_array(ind,:)
```

Output -

```
[19970101]    [18659]    [183]    '19980820'    '00018659'    'RUNYON L'     '00001534'    'MERRILL'
[19970101]    [18290]    [183]    '19981221'    '00018290'    'MANTON S'     '00001534'    'MERRILL'
[19970101]    [10280]    [183]    '19980819'    '00010280'    'BRENNAN S'    '00001534'    'MERRILL'
```

Comment: @Divakar, this code is also detecting an error in the first line `>> allstrc = cellfun(@num2str,FINALJOIN2,'uni',0);
Undefined function 'abs' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in num2str (line 65)
        xmax = double(max(abs(widthCopy(:))));`

Comment: If I ignore the first step then I have a problem because I cannot use the unique function if I don't have a cell array of strings! :(

Comment: I thought I had given you a +1 for this, but now I see I hadn't?

Comment: @user3557054 Not really sure why that `allstrc` isn't working for you,  because it is for me. It could be some data inconsistencies there. If possible, upload your actual input cell array - `FINALJOIN2` on some public sharing website and share the link here?

Comment: @LuisMendo Guess I didn't receive it earlier. But it's all good really, no biggy :)

Comment: @Divakar, thanks for your help. Meanwhile I made some changes on the code and on my data, and I was able to apply the code you suggested on each cell array separately before matching them. Now I am having some problems with matching the 'clean' cell-arrays, but later on today, if I don't manage to solve the problem I will post a new question! Thanks a lot, really!

Comment: @user3557054 Sure! Keep them coming!